# JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe web app

Tags: javascript, game, tic-tac-toe, dom

I am teaching myself JavaScript and made a little Tic-Tac-Toe web app. I'm not asking anyone to read through it all, but to just tell me what I need or should not do in the future.

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var boxtext = document.querySelectorAll("td span");
var player = document.querySelector("#player");
var playerTurnDisplay = document.querySelector("#playerTurnDisplay");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#resetButton");
var isXTurn = true;
var boxesLeftToClick = 9;
var gameOver = false;

function init() {
  addClickListeners(boxes);
}

function addClickListeners(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (isEmpty(this) && gameOver === false) {
          addObjectToBox(this);
          isXTurn = !(isXTurn);
          boxesLeftToClick--;
          displayTurn();
          checkWinner(arr);
        }
      });
      resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        reset();
      })
    }
  }
  // is the box empty [true] or does it have an X or O in it [false]

function isEmpty(box) {
    if (box.textContent !== "X" && box.textContent !== "O")
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
  // adds the Object "O" to the board

function addCross(box) {
    box.classList.add("cross");
    box.textContent = "X";
  }
  // adds the Object "X" to the board

function addCircle(box) {
    box.classList.add("circle");
    box.textContent = "O";
  }
  // displays whos turn it is to the players

function displayTurn() {
    if (boxesLeftToClick > 0) {
      player.textContent = (isXTurn) ? "X" : "O";
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.toggle("xTurn");
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.toggle("yTurn");
    } else {
      playerTurnDisplay.textContent = "Draw";
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.toggle(playerTurnDisplay.classList);
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.add("gameOver");
    }
  }
  // if someone wins get rid of the background color and display the text of whoever won

function setWinnerDisplay(box, orientation) {
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.remove("xTurn");
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.remove("yTurn");
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.add("gameOver");
    playerTurnDisplay.textContent = box.textContent + " wins " + orientation;
    gameOver = true;
  }
  // adds the "line" through the winning boxes

function crossOut(box1, box2, box3) {
    box1.classList.add("crossOut");
    box2.classList.add("crossOut");
    box3.classList.add("crossOut");
  }
  // all the things that need to happend when a player wins will happen if you call this function

function win(box1, box2, box3, orientation) {
    setWinnerDisplay(box1, orientation);
    crossOut(box1, box2, box3);
  }
  // returns true if the boxes are all X's or O's false if they are empty or not the same

function isTheSame(box1, box2, box3) {
  if (box1.textContent === box2.textContent && box1.textContent === box3.textContent && isEmpty(box1) === false) return true;
  else
    return false;
}

function reset() {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      boxes[i].textContent = "";
      isXTurn = true;
      boxes[i].classList.remove("crossOut");
      boxes[i].classList.remove("gameOver");
    }
    gameOver = false;
    if (isXTurn) playerTurnDisplay.classList.add("xTurn");
    boxesLeftToClick = 9;
  }
  // checks an array of 9 elements to see if their textContent is the same

function checkWinner(arr) {
  if (isTheSame(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]))
    win(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], "horizontally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]))
    win(arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], "horizontally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]))
    win(arr[6], arr[7], arr[8], "horizontally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[0], arr[3], arr[6]))
    win(arr[0], arr[3], arr[6], "vertically");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[1], arr[4], arr[7]))
    win(arr[1], arr[4], arr[7], "vertically");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[2], arr[5], arr[8]))
    win(arr[2], arr[5], arr[8], "vertically");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[0], arr[4], arr[8]))
    win(arr[0], arr[4], arr[8], "diagonally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[2], arr[4], arr[6]))
    win(arr[2], arr[4], arr[6], "diagonally");
}

function addObjectToBox(box) {
  if (isXTurn)
    addCross(box);
  else
    addCircle(box);
}

init();
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.gameOver {
  background: #14FF00;
  border: 3px solid #14FF00;
}
#nav-bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 430px;
}
button {
  margin: 0px auto 3px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 211px;
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: gold;
}
#playerTurnDisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 205px;
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
}
.xTurn {
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.yTurn {
  background: blue;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
table {
  margin: auto;
}
td {
  width: 205px;
  height: 205px;
  text-align: center;
}
.vertical {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.horizontal {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.circle {
  font-size: 150px;
  color: blue;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  --webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  --moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}
.cross {
  font-size: 150px;
  color: red;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  --webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  --moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}
.crossOut {
  background: gold;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  --webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  --moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TicTacToe</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <button id="resetButton">reset</button>
    <h3 class="xTurn" id="playerTurnDisplay"><span id="player">X</span>'s turn</h3>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span id="top-left"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="vertical"><span id="top-mid"></span>
        </td>
        <td><span id="top-right"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="horizontal"><span id="mid-left"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="vertical horizontal"><span id="mid-mid"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="horizontal"><span id="mid-right"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span id="bottom-left"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="vertical"><span id="bottom-mid"></span>
        </td>
        <td><span id="bottom-right"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="js/master.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'd use [some OOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects), if you've already learnt it.
Also do not put your code outside of functions, because it will [pollute the global scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted). You can use an [Immediately-Invocated-Function-Expression (IIFE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. Use [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to handle events (e.g. click) by inspecting the target of the event (e.g. with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)) to determine the action, instead of adding event handlers to each element (e.g. table cells, the reset button, etc.). That way if the elements ever get added/removed from the DOM, the event handlers won't be missing/lost, which could lead to memory leaks (which could eventually crash the browser).

   So the `addClickListeners()` function can be written like this:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
     if (clickEvent.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'TD') {
        cellClickHandler(clickEvent.target);
     } else if (clickEvent.target.id == 'resetButton') {
        reset();
     }
   });
   ```
2. Use a *functional programming* approach to iterate through the cells - e.g. with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of a `for` statement. To learn more about functional programming in JS, try going through [these exercises](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/). One of the major benefits is that you don't have to manually increment the iterator variable and then use that to index into the array - the item at each index is passed as a parameter to the callback function. Of course there are drawbacks to this approach, like the scope changes slightly.

   So the `reset()` function could be rewritten like this:

   ```
   function reset() {
     boxes.forEach(function(box) {
       box.textContent = "";
       box.classList.remove("crossOut");
       box.classList.remove("gameOver");
     });
     ...
   }
   ```
3. The logic for some functions like *isTheSame* and *isEmpty* can be simplified because the expressions for the if statements are booleans, and the functions themselves are booleans, so the expressions can be returned. For example:

   > ```
   > function isTheSame(box1, box2, box3) {
   >   if (box1.textContent === box2.textContent && box1.textContent === box3.textContent && isEmpty(box1) === false) return true;
   >   else
   >     return false;
   > }
   > ```

   can be re-written as:

   ```
   function isTheSame(box1, box2, box3) {
     return box1.textContent === box2.textContent && box1.textContent === box3.textContent && isEmpty(box1) === false;
   }
   ```
4. Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to select elements by Id attribute instead of using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and passing a hash character followed by the id.
   When I ran [this performance test](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector), the latter was `62% slower`. It likely doesn't make much of a difference for a small DOM structure like this but on a larger project it could. A different approach to selecting the table cells than using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) would be to select the table element and query under it for the table cells.

   ```
   var player = document.getElementById("player");
   var playerTurnDisplay = document.getElementById("playerTurnDisplay");
   var resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton");</pre>
   ```

See these changes in action below:

```js
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("td");
var boxtext = document.querySelectorAll("td span");
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var playerTurnDisplay = document.getElementById("playerTurnDisplay");
var resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton");
var isXTurn = true;
var boxesLeftToClick = 9;
var gameOver = false;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.addEventListener('click', function(clickEvent) {
    if (clickEvent.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'TD') {
      cellClickHandler(clickEvent.target);
    } else if (clickEvent.target.id == 'resetButton') {
      reset();
    }
  });
});

function cellClickHandler(target) {
  if (isEmpty(target) && gameOver === false) {
    addObjectToBox(target);
    isXTurn = !(isXTurn);
    boxesLeftToClick--;
    displayTurn();
    checkWinner(boxes);
  }
}
  // is the box empty [true] or does it have an X or O in it [false]

function isEmpty(box) {
    return box.textContent !== "X" && box.textContent !== "O";
  }
  // adds the Object "O" to the board

function addCross(box) {
    box.classList.add("cross");
    box.textContent = "X";
  }
  // adds the Object "X" to the board

function addCircle(box) {
    box.classList.add("circle");
    box.textContent = "O";
  }
  // displays whos turn it is to the players

function displayTurn() {
    if (boxesLeftToClick > 0) {
      player.textContent = (isXTurn) ? "X" : "O";
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.toggle("xTurn");
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.toggle("yTurn");
    } else {
      playerTurnDisplay.textContent = "Draw";
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.toggle(playerTurnDisplay.classList);
      playerTurnDisplay.classList.add("gameOver");
    }
  }
  // if someone wins get rid of the background color and display the text of whoever won

function setWinnerDisplay(box, orientation) {
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.remove("xTurn");
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.remove("yTurn");
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.add("gameOver");
    playerTurnDisplay.textContent = box.textContent + " wins " + orientation;
    gameOver = true;
  }
  // adds the "line" through the winning boxes

function crossOut(box1, box2, box3) {
    box1.classList.add("crossOut");
    box2.classList.add("crossOut");
    box3.classList.add("crossOut");
  }
  // all the things that need to happend when a player wins will happen if you call this function

function win(box1, box2, box3, orientation) {
    setWinnerDisplay(box1, orientation);
    crossOut(box1, box2, box3);
  }
  // returns true if the boxes are all X's or O's false if they are empty or not the same

function isTheSame(box1, box2, box3) {
  return box1.textContent === box2.textContent && box1.textContent === box3.textContent && isEmpty(box1) === false;
}

function reset() {
  boxes.forEach(function(box) {
      box.textContent = "";
      box.classList.remove("crossOut");
      box.classList.remove("gameOver");
    });
    isXTurn = true;
    gameOver = false;
    playerTurnDisplay.classList.add("xTurn");
    boxesLeftToClick = 9;
  }
  // checks an array of 9 elements to see if their textContent is the same

function checkWinner(arr) {
  if (isTheSame(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]))
    win(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], "horizontally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[3], arr[4], arr[5]))
    win(arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], "horizontally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[6], arr[7], arr[8]))
    win(arr[6], arr[7], arr[8], "horizontally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[0], arr[3], arr[6]))
    win(arr[0], arr[3], arr[6], "vertically");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[1], arr[4], arr[7]))
    win(arr[1], arr[4], arr[7], "vertically");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[2], arr[5], arr[8]))
    win(arr[2], arr[5], arr[8], "vertically");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[0], arr[4], arr[8]))
    win(arr[0], arr[4], arr[8], "diagonally");
  else if (isTheSame(arr[2], arr[4], arr[6]))
    win(arr[2], arr[4], arr[6], "diagonally");
}

function addObjectToBox(box) {
  if (isXTurn)
    addCross(box);
  else
    addCircle(box);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.gameOver {
  background: #14FF00;
  border: 3px solid #14FF00;
}
#nav-bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 430px;
}
button {
  margin: 0px auto 3px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 211px;
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: gold;
}
#playerTurnDisplay {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 205px;
  margin: 0px auto 20px auto;
}
.xTurn {
  background: red;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
.yTurn {
  background: blue;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
table {
  margin: auto;
}
td {
  width: 205px;
  height: 205px;
  text-align: center;
}
.vertical {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.horizontal {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.circle {
  font-size: 150px;
  color: blue;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  --webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  --moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}
.cross {
  font-size: 150px;
  color: red;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  --webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  --moz-transition: all 0.1s;
}
.crossOut {
  background: gold;
  color: black;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  --webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  --moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

```html
 <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
<div id="nav-bar">
  <button id="resetButton">reset</button>
  <h3 class="xTurn" id="playerTurnDisplay"><span id="player">X</span>'s turn</h3>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="top-left"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="vertical"><span id="top-mid"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="top-right"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="horizontal"><span id="mid-left"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="vertical horizontal"><span id="mid-mid"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="horizontal"><span id="mid-right"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="bottom-left"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="vertical"><span id="bottom-mid"></span>
      </td>
      <td><span id="bottom-right"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

**1.**

Consider using ES2015. Most of its features are there to make your life easier. Modern browsers support > 95% of it and for the rest there's transpilers/polyfills (babel).

**2.**

```
function isEmpty(box) {
  if (box.textContent !== "X" && box.textContent !== "O")
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

should be just

```
function isEmpty(box) {
  return box.textContent !== "X" && box.textContent !== "O"
}
```

This is general advice that is valid for other programming language. You can do the same for the *isTheSame* function.

I also feel like the condition should be `box.textContent === ''`; this is more in line with the *isEmpty* name.

**3.**

The *checkWinner* can be rewritten in a less repetitive fashion:

```
const winningCombination = [
  { triple: [0, 1, 2], name: 'horizontally' },
  { triple: [3, 4, 5], name: 'horizontally' },
  // etc
].find(({ triple }) => isTheSame(...triple))

if (winningCombination) {
  const { triple, name } = winningCombination
  win(...triple, name)
}
```

Why is an array better than that long if-else chain? Because you can potentially store these combinations in a separate file or even generate them. If you decide to have 4x4 tic-tac-toe you're going to get tired of typing them out explicitly.

It's generally a good idea to store data-heavy/table-looking code as data.

**4.**

Consider using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)/[`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of plain for loops. In both of your cases you don't care how you're iterating *arr*/*boxes*. Let `forEach`/`for ... of` concern themselves with *HOW* the iteration is done.